# unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker' 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, 64-bit

Recently, I decided to encrypt the hard drive with window bitlocker. After booting to Ubuntu, I am unable to open any of the drive as it said "No .Filesystem or .Encrypted interface on D-bus object." I tried using dislocker, and mount it, but I can't open the drive as I don't have the proper permission. Though in Sudo mode, it recognize the drive as Unknown type. I tried to mount it manually, it then say "unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'".

Comment: Sounds like BitLocker is doing its job, then 

Comment: I only encrypt the hard drive because I have seen a bunch of threads and post that stated you can use Bitlocker drive on Ubuntu. But you can't do that now?